# Create a new binary answer column in my data based on NA values

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to create a new column beside my data with 1 or 0s to indicate whether there is missing data so I can examine the randomness of the missing data.

My data looks like so (treatment and response)and I would like to add a 'missing' column:

```
treatment          response    Missing
black              136         0
white              NA          1 
black              102         0  
white              126         0
```

Comment: Why create a new column when you can use `response` column as filter with `is.na()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat <- transform(dat, Missing = as.integer(is.na(response)))
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 2):

If your original data is in data.frame `df` then following will simply do what you want.

```
df$Missing <- ifelse(is.na(df$response), 1,0)
```